QGIS and rasterio differences in processing/loading
I am working with large geotiff files and I am struggling to find a workflow that can actually handle them. Right now my biggest issue is that I can easily read all of these files in QGIS, indicating that I should mainly use it in my work process. However, QGIS crashes when I run my code through the python terminal, making it quite unreliable for my needs.
The alternative would be to use python directly. However, when I try to read the files through rasterio it consumes an extreme amount of memory. I cannot even run zonal statistics (which would be my end goal) since there is so little memory left, besides taking a long time to do anything with the data.
Do any of you understand where does this difference in handling raster files come from? QGIS reads the files almost instanteneously, whereas it takes around 8 minutes for rasterio to read them.

What I have done until now:
The original information I am trying to analyze was divided into three different .tif files. To import all of them directly (and consistently) I used QGIS to generate virtual layers.
In python, I have:

Read the .vrt file through rasterio. It takes around 8 minutes and then it takes more than 15 minutes just to plot the resulting array. Can I make this process as efficient as in QGIS? If so, (i believe) this would solve my problem.

In QGIS, I have:

Imported the .vrt file. It reads instantenously.
Run a .py script through the terminal to automatize my work. I have already confirmed that I can do the operations directly using the QGIS interface. However, when I run the python script throught QGIS terminal it freezes and, after a few minutes, crashes. Could I prevent this? If so, (i believe) it would solve my problem.

